# Infinte Looping After Update Event In GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am Facing a very strange Problem and Don't know how to put it. but will try my level best.

I have a grid view which consist file upload control and the file is stored in DB when the Update event is called. the file upload code is written as a function which is called as soon as update button is clicked.

Now everything is fine like when i click on update, the file gets updated in the DB, but the page goes into a infinite loop and it seems that something is being processed. after sometime, a dialog box appears in which i get an option to download the entire webpage in the format document was uploaded(Don't Know why, how this dialog box appears), but still the  page is in loop and being processed. I Have checked my code like hundred times, but still unable to find the problem.

Any solution would be welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Code For Upload Doc

```
rotected void UploadDoc(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GVTaskCompDept.Rows)
        {
            if ((row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                FileUpload FU = (FileUpload)GVTaskCompDept.Rows[i].Cells[8].FindControl("FileUpload1");

                string filePath = FU.PostedFile.FileName;
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

                if (filePath != null && filePath != "")
                {
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                    br.Close();
                    fs.Close();

                    string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FU.FileName).TrimStart(".".ToCharArray()).ToLower();
                    string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FU.FileName);

                    // string ContentType = "";
                    if (ext == "doc" || ext == "docx")
                        ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
                    else if (ext == "xlx" || ext == "xlsx" || ext == "xls")
                        ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    else if (ext == "jpeg" || ext == "jpeg")
                        ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                    else if (ext == "pdf")
                        ContentType = "application/pdf";

                    (Session)["Data"] = bytes;
                    (Session)["Name"] = name;
                    (Session)["Type"] = ContentType;
                }
                else
                {
                    (Session)["Data"] = null;
                    (Session)["Name"] = null;
                    (Session)["Type"] = null;
                }
            }
            i += 1;
        }
    }
```

The RowUpdating Event is as like

```
 protected void GVTaskCompDept_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {          
            GridViewRow gvrow = GVTaskCompDept.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            Session["rowindex"] = e.RowIndex;
            UploadDoc(null, null);              

     //---Some Code-----//       

            {
                DSTaskCompliance.UpdateParameters["UploadDocTitle"].DefaultValue = (Session)["Name"].ToString();
                DSTaskCompliance.UpdateParameters["UploadDocType"].DefaultValue = (Session["Type"]).ToString();
            }
 //-------Some Code---------//
 DSTaskCompliance.Update();
            DSTaskCompliance.DataBind();            
    }
```

Now in DataSource Updating Event, I Pass the session variable along with some other part of code to update it into DB

```
protected void DSTaskCompliance_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Command.Parameters["@UploadDocContent"].Value = Session["Data"];
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the code source plz?

Comment: plz place your code in order for us to help

Comment: Which code should i share. the code is too big actually. i mean which part

Comment: the part that is going into the infinite loop

Comment: Thats what i dont know, which part goes into infinte loop. just that after i click update button, it seems it processing and keeps on processing

Comment: then write your whole "related process" code, otherwise no one can help

Comment: Okay, One thing i forgot to mention, if i don not upload a file and just change some other fields in gridview, it works perfectly fine. the issue arises only when i upload a file.I will share the code for uploading file into DB

Comment: add the code in your question not here plz

Comment: @AliIssa : I Have added the code, Kindly check.

Comment: from where do you call UploadDoc?

Comment: @AliIssa :  I Just updated it again. this is the code which does the updation part

Comment: can you try removing this line "DSTaskCompliance.DataBind();" in the GVTaskCompDept_RowUpdating and try again

Comment: I Have tried it too. the page keeps on processing, values get updated in DB, But still seems like page is processing and dialog box appears.

Comment: try debugging your code to see where the code is being crashed

Comment: i think your `UploadDoc` function should have a signature like `UploadDoc(GridViewRow row)` and call that using the specific row which is being updated in the `RowUpdating` event.

Comment: I Have tried debugging. but the code doesn't crash at any moment. it comes out of everything and then the page appears which is still getting processed.

Answer (score 0):

You code as such does not make sense. Regardless of that, `UploadDoc` code is most likely to throw an exception at below line:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

The filePath is client side path (would be only file name in non IE browsers) and trying to open on server is bound to fail in production scenario. It is probably working in dev environment where client/server are both same machine.

As far as your specific problem is concerned, my suspicion is on the other part in the page - have you got any code within the page that tries to show/download the uploaded documents? Obviously, have you tried to debug around the issue by setting a break-point in visual studio etc

Comment: Yes, I Do have some code which is related to downloading of files. i too had suspicion on this part, tried after putting break point and all, but it din't work. the flow of execution of code never went to download part once the updated event was done with.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, Finally i could find solution to my problem. this was just a minor error. in the code above i have specified the 'ContentType' to be specific when whenever a particular type of file is upload. ex: for word files it was application/vnd.ms-word.

There is no need to specify this as i found that code finds the type on its own and stores the same in DB. i need not. due to specifying it as application, it always tend to download the file in the format being uploaded.

THANKS A LOT ALL FOR YOUR SUPPORT!!!!! :)